# Error: "The property offers is not recognized by Google for an object of type Offer" in Structured data

Tags: google-search-console, structured-data

I have added below html code to a product page on one of our websites:

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope="" itemprop="offers">
<div class="product-type-data">
    <div itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope="" itemprop="offers" class="price-box">
        <span id="product-price-118" class="regular-price">
            <span itemprop="price" class="price">30,00&nbsp;€</span>  
        </span>                        
    </div>

    <p class="availability in-stock">Verfügbarkeit: <span>Auf Lager</span></p>
    <meta content="http://schema.org/InStock" itemprop="availability">
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>                
<meta content="EUR" itemprop="priceCurrency">
<meta content="30" itemprop="price">
```

I'm receiving the Error: "The property offers is not recognized by Google for an object of type Offer" (Only for div having class "price-box" ) in Structured data when testing this in Webmaster Tools.

I am also attaching a error snapshot of webmaster here.
[image]
Is anyone able to point me in the right direction of where I'm going wrong?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old question, but I wanted to respond in case someone else needs an answer.  I am also going to make an assumption that the offer is for a product (this isn't required, but is probably very common for most people).

To begin, I want to refer to a few resources for reading about the subject.

https://schema.org/

[Google Structured Data Test Tool](https://search.google.com/structured-data/testing-tool)

[Google Product Reference](https://developers.google.com/search/docs/data-types/product)

I also want to clarify that the question pertains to Microdata, not JSON-LD, so I will respond with Microdata formatting.

I believe your problem is that you have an "offers" within an "offers".  Try this code:

```
<div itemprop="offers" itemscope itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer">
  <div class="product-type-data">
    <div class="price-box">
      <span id="product-price-118" class="regular-price">
        <span class="price">30,00&nbsp;€</span>  
      </span>                        
    </div>
    <p class="availability in-stock">Verfügbarkeit: <span>Auf Lager</span></p>
    <div class="clearfix"></div>
  </div>
  <meta content="http://schema.org/InStock" itemprop="availability">
  <meta content="30" itemprop="price">
  <meta content="EUR" itemprop="priceCurrency">
</div>
```

If you put the above code into the google testing tool, it will validate.

If you would like another example, go to the google product reference link above and in the examples section (Single product page), select the Microdata tab and then select "See Markup".  This will give you a more complete example.  I have included it below in case google ever removes this code.

```
<div itemtype="http://schema.org/Product" itemscope>
  <meta itemprop="mpn" content="925872" />
  <meta itemprop="name" content="Executive Anvil" />
  <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/16x9/photo.jpg" />
  <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/4x3/photo.jpg" />
  <link itemprop="image" href="https://example.com/photos/1x1/photo.jpg" />
  <meta itemprop="description" content="Sleeker than ACME's Classic Anvil, the Executive Anvil is perfect for the business traveler looking for something to drop from a height." />
  <div itemprop="offers" itemtype="http://schema.org/Offer" itemscope>
    <link itemprop="url" href="https://example.com/anvil" />
    <meta itemprop="availability" content="https://schema.org/InStock" />
    <meta itemprop="priceCurrency" content="USD" />
    <meta itemprop="itemCondition" content="https://schema.org/UsedCondition" />
    <meta itemprop="price" content="119.99" />
    <meta itemprop="priceValidUntil" content="2020-11-05" />
    <div itemprop="seller" itemtype="http://schema.org/Organization" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Executive Objects" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <div itemprop="aggregateRating" itemtype="http://schema.org/AggregateRating" itemscope>
    <meta itemprop="reviewCount" content="89" />
    <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4.4" />
  </div>
  <div itemprop="review" itemtype="http://schema.org/Review" itemscope>
    <div itemprop="author" itemtype="http://schema.org/Person" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="name" content="Fred Benson" />
    </div>
    <div itemprop="reviewRating" itemtype="http://schema.org/Rating" itemscope>
      <meta itemprop="ratingValue" content="4" />
      <meta itemprop="bestRating" content="5" />
    </div>
  </div>
  <meta itemprop="sku" content="0446310786" />
  <div itemprop="brand" itemtype="http://schema.org/Thing" itemscope>
    <meta itemprop="name" content="ACME" />
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

You can find examples of JSON+LD for Product type at https://schema.org/Product and for Offers https://schema.org/Offer but here's an example of:

```
<script type="application/ld+json">
{
  "@context": "http://schema.org",
  "@type": "Product",
  "aggregateRating": {
    "@type": "AggregateRating",
    "bestRating": "100",
    "ratingCount": "24",
    "ratingValue": "87"
  },
  "image": "dell-30in-lcd.jpg",
  "name": "Dell UltraSharp 30\" LCD Monitor",
  "offers": {
    "@type": "AggregateOffer",
    "highPrice": "$1495",
    "lowPrice": "$1250",
    "offerCount": "8",
    "offers": [
      {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "save-a-lot-monitors.com/dell-30.html"
      },
      {
        "@type": "Offer",
        "url": "jondoe-gadgets.com/dell-30.html"
      }
    ]
  }
}
</script>
```